# Why are there sixty seconds in one minute and sixty minutes in one hour, but sixty hours do not equal one day?

Tags: time

Why are there sixty seconds in one minute and sixty minutes in one hour, but sixty hours do not equal one day?

Comment: See [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/experts-time-division-days-hours-minutes/).

Comment: There may be an historical explanation for this that might have philosophic interest. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: 12 is strictly related to 60. See [A Brief History of Time Measurement](https://nrich.maths.org/6070) : "There are various theories about how the 24 hour day developed. The fact that the day was divided into 12 hours might be because 12 is a factor of 60, and both the Babylonian and Egyptian civilisations recognised a zodiac cycle of 12 constellations. On the other hand, finger-counting with base 12 was a possibility. The fingers each have 3 joints, and so counting on the joints gives one 'full hand' of 12."

Comment: I made an edit to hopefully clarify the question. You may roll this back or continue editing. Again, welcome!

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with philosophy. It is an interesting question but it does not belong on this specific SE site.

Comment: Sorry but tell me which is correct forum for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alan Longstaff](https://www.rmg.co.uk/discover/explore/why-12-months-year-seven-days-week-or-60-minutes-hour) provides an explanation for why minutes and hours are divided into sixty parts:

> When the hour was divided into 60 minutes, consisting of 60 seconds, the number 60 was probably chosen for its mathematical convenience. It is divisible by a large number of smaller numbers without a remainder: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20 and 30.

He offers this explanation for why there are twenty-four parts in a day:

> The Ancient Egyptians were the first to use 24 hours to divide the day. They divided the day into 12 hours from sunrise to sunset, and the night into a further 12 hours from sunset to sunrise.

The question, however, asks why are there not sixty hours in a day. Based on the Longstaff's information former astronomers made choices. Their successors followed those choices teaching them to the next generator. We are most recent in that tradition.

---

Longstaff A, "Why 12 months in a year, seven days in a week or 60 minutes in an hour?", Royal Museums Greenwich 
https://www.rmg.co.uk/discover/explore/why-12-months-year-seven-days-week-or-60-minutes-hour